# How to install multiple dependencies using a shell script on mac os?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I am looking to install multiple dependencies on Mac OS using a shell script.This is mainly a environment setup for a software, that I am looking to finish using a single script rather than a running each of them separately.

Currently my script looks as below. I am saving the script file with `.command` extension and when I double click it, it installs `Homebrew` however, it **doesn't** install further dependencies ie `wine` and `stunnel`. Any idea how this can be done?

Any help is really appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
installCommandLineDevTools(){
if xcode-select --install 2>&1 | grep installed; then
    echo command line tools already installed;
else
    echo command line developer tools not installed;
    echo installing command line tools;
 fi
 }

 installHomeBrew(){
 if which brew > /dev/null; then
    echo Homebrew is installed
 else
    echo Homebrew is not installed.
    echo Installing Homebrew....
    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL 
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
 fi
 }

 installWine(){
 if ! type which wine > /dev/null; then
     echo install latest wine version
     brew install wine
 else
    echo wine already installed;
 fi
}

installStunnel(){
if ! type which stunnel > /dev/null; then
    echo install latest stunnel
    brew install stunnel
else
  echo stunnel already installed;
 fi 
}

#Invoke your functions
installCommandLineTools
installHomeBrew
installWine
installStunnel
```

Comment: Use the bash -x flag for debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because there is already wine or stunnel in path.

In command

```
type which stunnel
```

`which` is useless

May be

```
! type stunnel
```

or

```
! which stunnel
```

or

```
! type stunnel && ! which stunnel
```

Comment: Also, it would be nice it the OP would stuck to one convention. Because there are two used: `if installed then message else install` and `if not installed then install else message`. There is no reason to put in use both of them.